# Simple API Get request not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm attempting to do a simple get request to pull a random quote from this API. Hardcoding to change the quote on the button click works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quotebtn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json',
      success: function(data) {
        var post = data.shift(); //get the first quote
        $('#quote').html(post.content); //change the html to the quote

      },
      cache: false
    });
    // $("#quote").html("You clicked!");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <h1>Quote Machine</h1>
  <div id="quote">Here is the quote</div>
  <button id="quotebtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
     Button
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/stepup2stepout/pen/gxZVWz?editors=1010' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json?_=1504721878738'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your commentary: `Mixed Content: The page at 'codepen.io/stepup2stepout/pen/gxZVWz?editors=1010'; was loaded over HTTPS...` you shouldn't mix HTTP and HTTPS. The page you're querying does not have a secure counterpart.

Mixed content aside, the response of the server is not an array, is an object, you can't `.shift()` objects, only arrays.

instead of:

```
function(data) {
    var post = data.shift(); //get the first quote
    $('#quote').html(post.content); //change the html to the quote
  }
```

try:

```
function(data) {
    $('#quote').html(data.quote); //change the html to the quote
  }
```

[Mixed Content (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Answer (score 0):

the data returned from the api;

```
{
    "author": "Charles Babbage",
    "id": 8,
    "quote": "On two occasions I have been asked, \u2018Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?\u2019 I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.\u201d",
    "permalink": "http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/quotes/8"
}
```

as you see it is not an array so you don't need to do `data.shift()`. 
just doing;
`$('#quote').html(data.quote);`
will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning a single JSON object and not an Array. So there is no necessity of doing a shift operation.

Below code should do the trick for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#quotebtn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json',
        success: function(data) {
            var post = data.quote; //get the first quote
            $('#quote').html(post); //change the html to the quote
        },
        cache: false
    });
  })
})
```